# Save selected choices on another object

Tags: apex

I have 3 custom objects- Question, Question Choices and Answers. Lookup has been defined on Question Choices to Question object and another lookup has been defined on Question object to Lead. I am displaying a question with all the related choices to that question on a page (This has been done). Whenever a Lead selects the choices of any question, that selected question's record should get saved on Answer's object. In addition to that all the selected answers should be related to that specific Lead who has attempted the questions.

This is what I have done till now... I have created a page where I'm displaying parent object's (Question__C) records along with their related child records (QuestionChoice__c) as checkbox. My requirement is I need to save the selected child records to a differnt object. Could you please help me with an example or a sample code.

My Page-

```
    <script>
    var flag=0;
    var SelectConId1='';
    function checkAll(cb)
    {    
        flag=0;
        SelectConId1='';
        var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=1; i<inputElem.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
            {
                inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
                flag=flag+1;
                SelectConId1=SelectConId1+inputElem[i].name+',';
            }
        }
        if(cb.checked!=true)
        {
            SelectConId1="";
            flag=0;
        } 
        //alert(SelectConId1);

    }

    function checkone(cb,conid)
    {         

       var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=1; i<inputElem.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
            {
                if(inputElem[i].name!=cb.name && cb.className==inputElem[i].className)
                {
                    inputElem[i].checked=false;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    function search_element()
    {
        //alert('hello');
        var element=document.getElementById("searchtext").value;
       // alert(element);
        searchelement(element);
        return false;
    }
    function addtolist()
    {

        if((SelectConId1.length)<=1)
        {
            alert('Please select at least one Answer Choice');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            addtolistcontact();
        }
    }

    function addtolistcontact()
    {    
    }
    function closethis()
    {

    }
    </script>        
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false">
            <apex:repeat var="q" value="{!wrapList}">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!q.ques.Title__c}" columns="1" >
                    <apex:pageBlockTable var="qc" value="{!q.qcList}" id="quesList">            
                       <apex:column >
                 <input type="checkbox" class="{!q.ques.Id}" name="{!qc.id}" id="checkedone"  onclick="return checkone(this,'{!qc.id}')"  /> 
                </apex:column>
            <div id="{!qc.id}">
             <apex:column >
                <!--<apex:facet name="header" >Name</apex:facet>-->
                {!qc.Title__c}
                    </apex:column>
               </div>                                                                                                      
                   </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>   
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

My Controller-

```
public class QuestionController{    
   public List<wrap> wrapList{get; set;}   
   public QuestionController(){
       wrapList = new List<wrap>();
       showRecords(); 
   }

    public void showRecords(){
        //String  selectedId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pid');
        List<Question__c> quesList = [select id,Title__c,(select id, Name, Title__c from QuestionChoices__r), Name from Question__c ];
        for(Question__c q :quesList){

            List<QuestionChoice__c>qcList = q.QuestionChoices__r;
            wrapList.add(new wrap(q,qcList));
        }        
    }

     public class wrap{
        public Question__c ques{get; set;}
        public List<QuestionChoice__c> qcList{get; set;}

        public wrap(Question__c ques, List<QuestionChoice__c> qcList){
            this.ques = ques;
            this.qcList = qcList;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Note that the question you posted already http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45480/save-sselected-choices-gets-save-on-another-object is being voted on for re-opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to save the Id of the QuestionChoice onto some other object, I'd go this way:

Add a couple of action functions (these get rendered as a small javascript function with hooks back to the controller. They accept parameters so you can pass data to the controller too.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="check"  action="{!check}" rerender="yourTable" >
    <apex:param name="qcId" assignTo="{!qcId}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="uncheck"  action="{!uncheck}" rerender="yourTable" >
    <apex:param name="qcId" assignTo="{!qcId}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Call these in your checkone function:

```
function checkone(cb,conid){         
   var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var checked = true;

    for(var i=1; i<inputElem.length; i++){
        if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1){
            if(inputElem[i].name!=cb.name && cb.className==inputElem[i].className){
                inputElem[i].checked=false;
                //call uncheck actionfunction:
                uncheck(conid);
                checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (checked){
        check(conid);
    }
}
```

Now you are passing data back to the controller each time you check / uncheck your inputs.

From here you could save every time you check / uncheck or have a "Save" button.

Hopefully this is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks alot for your valuable inputs. Could you please also help me with the check and uncheck functions/ methods.

Comment: Thanks... I have made changes in my code and a record is being inserted in Answer object. Now my requirement is I only want to save the selected Question Choice ID in Answer object. How to continue with this. Here is the save method written  so far                                             " public PageReference save() {
    
    Answer__c a = new Answer__c (Name=names, Title__c=title ,QuestionChoice_ID__c=quescho, Lead_ID__c=leadid, Contact__c=Contacts);    
    insert a;
    
        return null;
    }"

Comment: @SalesforceLearner: if some post / reply has helped in a way to move forward then you `Vote Up` and if you got the answer for what you **asked** then you should mark that post as an answer for other users to help when they would search for similar questions.